# why choose bluetooth over wifi-direct for an ad-hoc-network

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, ad-hoc-network

I always thought, that wifi opposed to bluetooth is mostly used to connect to a hotspot and that most desktop wifi chips lack the possibility to use them as a wifi hotspot (while its no problem with the chips used in smartphones). Apparently this is not the case since newer chips have [support for wifi-direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct).

(I used bluetooth to build an ad-hoc-network (I would call it a mesh like network) but only found out about wifi-direct now.)

**Question:**

**I was wondering what advantage bluetooth 4.0 LE has over [wifi direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) other than the possibly lower energy consumption (accept that newer bluetooth 4.1+ can send and receive at the same time as far as I know).**

There are of course multiple pages who show the differences, according to [this one](https://techspirited.com/wi-fi-direct-vs-bluetooth40) for example the only advantage of bluetooth 4.0 LE over wifi-direct it the possibly lower energy consumption.

So if I would have to argue why I used bluetooth 4.0 LE over wifi-direct I would have to say that I did so because bluetooth 4.0 LE might reduce energy consumption.

- [This review](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/the-differences-between-bluetooth-4-0-and-wi-fi-direct-you-need-to-know/) also seems to come to the same conclusion.
- [This review](https://www.lifewire.com/bluetooth-vs-wi-fi-4088218) claims that bluetooth is still more important in the
  OEM    market at least in the short term.

**Additional Information:**

Range and bandwidth are the advantages of wifi-direct, I'm searching for advantages of bluetooth 4.0 LE, In my case I transfare only small amounts of data (json files around 4 Kilobyte) over a short distance between 1-5 Meters, so this does not matter. Currently I try to find out whether its easier to set up bluetooth than wifi-direct e.g. if this might be an advantage of bluetooth 4.0 LE over wifi-direct.

Comment: Range would be an important difference...

Comment: range and bandwidth are the advantages of wifi-direct, I'm searching for advantages of bluetooth, In my case I transfare only small amounts of data (json files  around 4 Kilobyte)  over a short distance between 1-5 Meters, so this does not matter.                                         Currently I try to find out whether its easier to set up bluetooth than wifi-direct e.g. if this might be an advantage of bluetooth

Comment: That additional info would be a good [edit] to your question.